Question about KinematicTrajectoryOptimization AddPathVelocityConstraint
I want to constraints velocity at a specify position, for example set start and end velocity to zero.
KinematicTrajectoryOptimization provider two api:
AddPathVelocityConstraint and AddVelocityConstraintAtNormalizedTime.

AddPathVelocityConstraint implement does NOT directly constrain q̇(t),
AddVelocityConstraintAtNormalizedTime implement use nonconvex generic constraints

my question is how to constrain q̇(t) using liner constraint ?
is it ok to use below formula ? :
 q̇(t) = drds * dsdt = ṙ(s) / duration,
 duration * lb <= ṙ(s) <= duration * ub.

and corrspends implment will be
KinematicTrajectoryOptimization::AddPathVelocityConstraint(
    const Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::VectorXd>& lb,
    const Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::VectorXd>& ub, double s) {
  const VectorX<symbolic::Expression> sym_rdot_value = sym_rdot_->value(s);
  auto binding =
      prog_.AddLinearConstraint(lb * duration_ <= sym_rdot_value && sym_rdot_value <= ub * duration_);
  binding.evaluator()->set_description("path real velocity constraint");
  return binding;
}


Yes, I think you can do that.

Yes, it appears to be a valid approach. The code implementation with AddLinearConstraint correctly applies the linear velocity constraint in the trajectory optimization problem. Just ensure that duration_ is correctly set and that the bounds (lb and ub) are appropriately chosen.
